# Are there any uninitialized values in my code?

Tags: c, memory

I was studying about structures in C and tried defining a matrix structure, which includes the dimensions (rows, cols), and a pointer to the memory allocated for the entries. The code works fine, but valgrind says I have uninitialized values. I was wondering if anyone could tell me where this is coming from. I'm using macOS Mojave. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _matrix {
  int rows;
  int cols;
  double** address;
} Matrix;

Matrix* makeMatrix(void);

int main(void) {
  printf("Please enter the dimensions of your matrix A:");
  Matrix* A = NULL;
  A = makeMatrix();
  for (int i = 0; i < (*A).rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < (*A).cols; ++j)
      (A->address)[i][j] = 1;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < (*A).rows; ++i)
    free((A->address)[i]);
  free(A->address);
  free(A);
}

Matrix* makeMatrix(void){
  int rows = 0; int cols = 0;
  Matrix* matrix = (Matrix*)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
  do {
    printf("\n\tRows = ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
  } while (rows < 1);
  do {
    printf("\tCols = ");
    scanf("%d", &cols);
  } while (cols < 1);
  (*matrix).rows = rows;
  (*matrix).cols = cols;
  (*matrix).address = (double**)malloc(rows*sizeof(double*));
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    *((*matrix).address+i) = (double*)malloc(cols*sizeof(double));
  return matrix;
}
```

and this is the valgrind output:

```
--12285-- run: /usr/bin/dsymutil "./matrix"
==12285== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12285==    at 0x10000D3B0: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x1000084F5: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x100008035: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285== 
==12285== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12285==    at 0x10000F4E9: dyld::checkEnvironmentVariables(char const**) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000D3B9: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x1000084F5: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x100008035: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285== 
==12285== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12285==    at 0x100009BD2: dyld::processDyldEnvironmentVariable(char const*, char const*, char const*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000F5F6: dyld::checkEnvironmentVariables(char const**) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000D3B9: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x1000084F5: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x100008035: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285== 
==12285== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12285==    at 0x10000D3C1: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x1000084F5: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x100008035: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285== 
==12285== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12285==    at 0x100011585: dyld::loadPhase3(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x100010EF1: dyld::loadPhase1(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000AAEE: dyld::loadPhase0(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000A642: dyld::load(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000E430: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x1000084F5: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x100008035: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285== 
==12285== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12285==    at 0x100011585: dyld::loadPhase3(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x100010EF1: dyld::loadPhase1(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000AAEE: dyld::loadPhase0(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000A67D: dyld::load(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000E430: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x1000084F5: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x100008035: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285== 
--12285-- UNKNOWN fcntl 98!
--12285-- UNKNOWN fcntl 98! (repeated 2 times)
--12285-- UNKNOWN fcntl 98! (repeated 4 times)
--12285-- UNKNOWN fcntl 98! (repeated 8 times)
--12285-- UNKNOWN fcntl 98! (repeated 16 times)
--12285-- UNKNOWN fcntl 98! (repeated 32 times)
==12285== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12285==    at 0x10015000B: ccaes_vng_ctr_crypt (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10014FF2B: bcc_update (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100151151: df_bcc_update (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100150F31: df (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10014F87F: nistctr_init (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10014F732: init (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10032235A: arc4_init (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100322478: arc4random_buf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10060844D: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100607472: appendHeader (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10061B278: _class_remap (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10000C570: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285== 
==12285== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12285==    at 0x10015000B: ccaes_vng_ctr_crypt (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10014FF2B: bcc_update (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1001511E1: df_bcc_update (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100150F31: df (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10014F87F: nistctr_init (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10014F732: init (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10032235A: arc4_init (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100322478: arc4random_buf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10060844D: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100607472: appendHeader (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10061B278: _class_remap (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10000C570: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285== 
==12285== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12285==    at 0x10015000B: ccaes_vng_ctr_crypt (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10014FF2B: bcc_update (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100150F90: df (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10014F87F: nistctr_init (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10014F732: init (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10032235A: arc4_init (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100322478: arc4random_buf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10060844D: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100607472: appendHeader (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10061B278: _class_remap (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10000C570: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000C699: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285== 
==12285== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12285==    at 0x10015000B: ccaes_vng_ctr_crypt (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10015103F: df (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10014F87F: nistctr_init (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10014F732: init (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10032235A: arc4_init (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100322478: arc4random_buf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10060844D: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100607472: appendHeader (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10061B278: _class_remap (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10000C570: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000C699: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10025C516: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==12285== 
==12285== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12285==    at 0x100151323: drbg_update (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10014F93E: nistctr_init (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10014F732: init (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10032235A: arc4_init (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100322478: arc4random_buf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10060844D: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100607472: appendHeader (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10061B278: _class_remap (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10000C570: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000C699: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10025C516: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100606C33: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285== 
==12285== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12285==    at 0x10015000B: ccaes_vng_ctr_crypt (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10015154B: generate (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1003224E3: arc4random_buf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10060844D: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100607472: appendHeader (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10061B278: _class_remap (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10000C570: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000C699: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10025C516: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100606C33: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1001F25C7: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1001FE3AA: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==12285== 
==12285== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12285==    at 0x10015000B: ccaes_vng_ctr_crypt (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1001512A6: drbg_update (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100151596: generate (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1003224E3: arc4random_buf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10060844D: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100607472: appendHeader (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10061B278: _class_remap (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10000C570: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000C699: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10025C516: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100606C33: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1001F25C7: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==12285== 
==12285== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12285==    at 0x1001512C3: drbg_update (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100151596: generate (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1003224E3: arc4random_buf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10060844D: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100607472: appendHeader (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10061B278: _class_remap (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10000C570: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000C699: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10025C516: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100606C33: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1001F25C7: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1001FE3AA: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==12285== 
==12285== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12285==    at 0x100151323: drbg_update (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100151596: generate (in /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1003224E3: arc4random_buf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10060844D: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100607472: appendHeader (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10061B278: _class_remap (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10000C570: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000C699: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10025C516: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x100606C33: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1001F25C7: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1001FE3AA: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==12285== 
==12285== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12285==    at 0x10061024C: objc_initializeClassPair_internal(objc_class*, char const*, objc_class*, objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1005B16AC: _libxpc_initializer (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1001019C9: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10001FCC7: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001FEC5: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001B0D9: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001B06C: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001A253: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001A2E7: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000972D: dyld::initializeMainExecutable() (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000E78E: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x1000084F5: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285== 
==12285== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==12285==    at 0x10061024E: objc_initializeClassPair_internal(objc_class*, char const*, objc_class*, objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1005B16AC: _libxpc_initializer (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1001019C9: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10001FCC7: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001FEC5: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001B0D9: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001B06C: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001A253: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001A2E7: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000972D: dyld::initializeMainExecutable() (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000E78E: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x1000084F5: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285== 
==12285== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==12285==    at 0x100610260: objc_initializeClassPair_internal(objc_class*, char const*, objc_class*, objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1005B16AC: _libxpc_initializer (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1001019C9: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10001FCC7: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001FEC5: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001B0D9: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001B06C: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001A253: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001A2E7: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000972D: dyld::initializeMainExecutable() (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000E78E: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x1000084F5: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285== 
==12285== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==12285==    at 0x10061027E: objc_initializeClassPair_internal(objc_class*, char const*, objc_class*, objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1005B16AC: _libxpc_initializer (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1001019C9: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10001FCC7: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001FEC5: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001B0D9: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001B06C: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001A253: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001A2E7: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000972D: dyld::initializeMainExecutable() (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000E78E: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x1000084F5: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285== 
==12285== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==12285==    at 0x10061028C: objc_initializeClassPair_internal(objc_class*, char const*, objc_class*, objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1005B16AC: _libxpc_initializer (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x1001019C9: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==12285==    by 0x10001FCC7: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001FEC5: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001B0D9: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001B06C: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001A253: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10001A2E7: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000972D: dyld::initializeMainExecutable() (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x10000E78E: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285==    by 0x1000084F5: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==12285== 
Please enter the dimensions of your matrix B:
    Rows = 1
    Cols = 1
==12285== 
==12285== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12285==     in use at exit: 27,287 bytes in 167 blocks
==12285==   total heap usage: 191 allocs, 24 frees, 35,767 bytes allocated
==12285== 
==12285== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12285==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12285==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12285==      possibly lost: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==12285==    still reachable: 4,296 bytes in 7 blocks
==12285==         suppressed: 22,919 bytes in 157 blocks
==12285== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==12285== 
==12285== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12285== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==12285== ERROR SUMMARY: 424 errors from 27 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Comment: You are not showing the whole code. Where is the main function?

Comment: @DYZ `main` function is there in the code.

Comment: Wouldn't your compiler tell you if you used uninitialized variables? If not increase the warning level.

Comment: Running this code under valgrind on Linux is clean.  Please post the **full** valgrind output.

Comment: Technically, after `scanf("%d", &rows);` the value in `rows` is not certain should `scanf();` return EOF.  Best to check its return value. Also return values from `malloc()` are not checked.

Comment: @chux How does one check `malloc()` return values?

Comment: When `malloc()` fails, it return `NULL`, so after `Matrix* matrix = malloc(...);` Robust code checks with `if(matrix == NULL) Handle_OutOfMemorySomehow()`.  Unknown if this affect your valgrind report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The valgrind output is complaining about modules that have nothing to do with your code.

Everything it lists is related to issues in internal libraries.  If there was a problem with your code, it would specify the name of your source file in one of the output lines.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm new to coding so I'm not familiar with much of the terminology used by the programs. I just read uninitialized values and freaked out lol

Comment: @AlexD: now you need to learn how to generate suppressions and save them to a file and then use the file when you run Valgrind so that you don’t have to wade through as much noise each time you use it.  In my experience, I end up doing this each time I get Valgrind running on macOS.